# Fetch delete request method using react redux is not deleting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch-api, http-delete

i'm trying to use fetch delete request method to delete item in my localhost server using react redux

method to call

```
 deleteItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = this.props.id;
    this.props.deleteSet(id);
  }
```

Dispatching the action

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  deleteSet: id => dispatch(deleteSet(id)),
});
```

Action

```
export function deleteSetSuccess(id) {
  return {
    type: "DELETE_SET_SUCCESS",
    id,
  };
}

export function deleteSet(data) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(`${apiUrl}orgs/1/sets/${data}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }),
    }).then(response => response)
      .then(id => dispatch(deleteSetSuccess(id)));
  };
}
```

Reducer

```
export function deleteSetSuccess(state = '', action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "DELETE_SET_SUCCESS":
      return action.id;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

response from the localhost server

```
DELETE http://localhost:8080/distinction-2.0-alpha2/api/orgs/1/sets/8 400 (Bad Request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [valid HTTP `DELETE` request doesn’t have a request body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE)—and so doesn’t need a `Content-Type` request header either—but the request code in the question is sending some data as the request body, along with a `Content-Type` request header. Presumably your server is deciding that’s not a valid `DELETE` request and so it’s responding with a 400 “Bad Request” to indicate that.

Comment: It works thanks, but it doesn't remove the item instantly, i have to refresh the page before it is gone.

Comment: And there is this issue i encounter, i have a list of components, what i want is  when ever i click an edit button on the each components it should take me to a page that has a bunch input where the input value is the this.props waiting for me to edit and save, and i have no idea how to start.