# How to Delete data with fetch request "DELETE" React + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, fetch

I was trying to delete data/object from my database with fetch delete request method,  using  React hooks and Redux.

I got stuck and I couldn’t  find an answer for my question.

Eventually some how I came across a solution,

Using the question  [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45654080/fetch-delete-request-method-using-react-redux-is-not-deleting)

and converting the solution that will fit React Hooks and Redux, I used "useDispatch"
instead "mapDispatchToProps"

First you need to import "useDispatch" from react-redux, and your Delete function from actions

```js
import { deleteSet } from './Actions'
import { connect ,useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
```

Then you can declare dispatch inside your functional component

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

The method to call

```js
// take the id of the itme/object you want to delete
const deleteItem = (item) => {
    const itemId = item._id
    console.log(itemId);
// use the dispatch you declared earlier with the function you import from Actions
    dispatch(deleteSet(itemId));
};
```

The Delete function from "Actions"

```js
export const deleteSet = (id) => (dispatch) =>  {
    fetch(`/api/orders/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    })
    .then(response => response)
    .then(id => dispatch(
      {
        type: DELETE_ITEM,
        payload: deleteSet(id)
       }
      ))  
    }
```

This is the reducer

```js
switch (action.type) {
        case DELETE_ITEM:
            return {item: action.payload};
        default:
           return state
    };
```

This is the  server.js I use for this delete function

```js
app.delete("/api/orders/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const order = await Order.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
    res.send(order)
})
```

---

I hope that this will help you in your journey

If someone  have improvements to this post Definitely post it below
Thank you and have  fun coding

Comment: What's the question? What result do you expect?

Comment: you miss understood I solved it already. but because I couldn’t  find  an answer here I wrote  my answer  that i came up with